# Properly Uninstall MongoDB via Command Line

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I've installed MongoDB version **i686-2.2.3** from source, in a Ubuntu 12.10 box. Now I want to remove it.

How can I do it properly?

Best wishes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed from source you would not have compiled it but instead just extracted the tar it came in and ran it.

The very first thing you need to do is figure out what additional stuff you put on, i.e.: a `init.d` script.

Once you remove all the additional threads you have created you can remove the directory that houses the mongo binary, normally a folder called `mongo` on most systems and then you need to delete your data directory, normally `/data/db/` under the source version.

Of course, this assumes you installed from source and not a package, if you installed from a package you can do:

```
apt-get remove --purge mongodb
```

#### Edit

Alternatively if you are using `autoremove`:

```
apt-get autoremove --purge mongodb
```

Comment: hi @Sammaye, i do not put anything on init.d. should i look other files/directories?

Comment: @PauloZanetti Nah just remove the folder that contains the mongodb binary and remove /data/db and your done